# Problema de lectura de colecciones con usuario en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Actualmente creé varios usuarios para la BD en MongoDB. Un usuario administrador y otros extras, dependiendo de las normas establecidas en la empresa. 
Resulta que uno de esos usuarios lo creé para que solo tenga permisos de ***lectura*** de algunas colecciones de una base de datos específica. No quiero que tenga acceso de lectura a una DB entera, solo a algunas de sus colecciones. 
Además, tengo otros usuarios que en una misma DB difieren los niveles de permisos (algunos solo lectura, otros lectura/escritura).

Paso script que genera el usuario administrador y el usuario en cuestión:

```js
use admin;
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "__EXAMPLE_PWD_ADMINISTRATOR__",
    roles: [
      { role: "root", db: "admin" }
    ]
  }
)

use products;
db.createRole(
  {
    role: "role-read-user",
    privileges: [
      {
        resource: { db: "products", collection: "products" },
        actions: [
          "changeStream",
          "collStats",
          "dbHash",
          "dbStats",
          "find",
          "killCursors",
          "listCollections",
          "listIndexes",
          "planCacheRead"
        ]
      },
      {
        resource: { db: "products", collection: "sales" },
        actions: [
          "changeStream",
          "collStats",
          "dbHash",
          "dbStats",
          "find",
          "killCursors",
          "listCollections",
          "listIndexes",
          "planCacheRead"
        ]
      }
    ],
    roles: []
  }
);


use products;
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "read-user",
    pwd: "__EXAMPLE_PWD_READ_USER__",
    roles: [
      { role: "role-read-user", db: "products" },
      { role: "role-read-user", db: "backup" }
    ]
  }
);

...
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Se crean los usuarios sin problemas. Pero a veces (no siempre) se me genera una excepción, la cual me indica que no puedo ejecutar el método *listCollections*, siendo que el usuario lo tiene indicado explícitamente.

```
OperationFailure: not authorized on products to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: {}, nameOnly: true, ...}
```

Llegando al caso que en aplicaciones como Studio3t o NSB no es posible hacer uso del usuario, porque no puede listar las colecciones.

Aclaración: que esto no ocurra siempre es porque lo testeé en una PC y la conexión, y el listado de colecciones se realiza sin problemas, pero en muchos casos presenta lo mencionado anteriormente.

EDIT:
Adjunto captura de lo que ocurre al utilizar NSB. Vía SSH me conecto al server donde se aloja la DB. Conecta sin problemas, pero a la hora de ver las colecciones de una DB (la de 0.79GB en este caso) salta esa alerta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Studio3T directamente muestra que la DB tiene 0 colecciones. 
Pero, como mencioné anteriormente, en algunos casos ocurre esto, ya que en mi computadora funciona sin problemas el listado de colecciones. Incluso la DB del servidor me muestra las colecciones al ejecutar show collections o db.getCollectionNames() (obviamente autenticándome con el usuario indicado arriba)

¿Será un tema más del lado del cliente? Porque con pymongo (v3.10, librería de python) también sale ese error (este sí en todos).

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo del llamado a `listCollections` que estás haciendo?

Comment: Edité la respuesta para poder agregar la imagen del problema ahí.

Comment: Creo que es un tema más de los clientes que se conectan al servidor y no de este último.
Probé con diferentes aplicaciones (Studio3T y NSB) para que se conecten y se autentiquen con el mismo usuario. Luego, al correr ***db.getCollectionNames()***, lista las colecciones sin problemas el primero, pero en el caso de la 2da aplicación no y me sale el mismo error que publiqué anteriormente.